# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-i/n}z$, $z\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-i/n}z$$ $z\in\mathbb{R}$

How to find such limit? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-i/n}z\to e^0z=z$ as $n \to \infty,$ since $\exp$ is continuous.

Comment: I think your first $=$ should be a $\to$.